# Использование multiiprocessing увеличивает время выполнения

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Без multiprocessing время выполнения - 7 секунд. С ним - Более 5 минут. Как правильно использовать multiprocessing?

```
for global_cycle in range(30000):

    data_z = {}
    dw = {}
    
    for spliting_cycle in range(quan_of_spliting):
        data_z_ninside, data_z_inside = Pipe()
    
        p = Process(target=forward, args=(w_slovar["Split " + str(spliting_cycle)], data_z_inside, x,))
        p.start()
        
        data_z["Split " + str(spliting_cycle)] = data_z_ninside.recv()
    p.join()
    
    for spliting_cycle in range(quan_of_spliting):  
        cost_nin, cost_inside = Pipe()
        dw_nin, dw_inside = Pipe()
        
        p2 = Process(target=backward, args=(cost_inside, dw_inside, w_slovar["Split " + str(spliting_cycle)], data_z["Split " + str(spliting_cycle)], y,))
        p2.start()

        cost += cost_nin.recv() 
        dw["Split " + str(spliting_cycle)] = dw_nin.recv()
    p2.join()
    
    for spliting_cycle in range(quan_of_spliting):  
        w_slovar_nin, w_slovar_inside = Pipe()
        p3 = Process(target=update_weights, args=(dw["Split " + str(spliting_cycle)], w_slovar["Split " + str(spliting_cycle)], w_slovar_inside, learning_rate))
        p3.start()
        
        w_slovar["Split " + str(spliting_cycle)] = w_slovar_nin.recv()
    p3.join()
```

Comment: А сколько вы тут процессов в итоге используете ? Запуск процесса это безумно долгая операция. А у вас тут цикл на 30к итераций который запускает процессы и явно не по одному. Правильное использование: запускаете несколько процессов, примерно столько сколько ядер и раздаете им работу по мере того как они ее выполняют

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `from multiprocessing import Pool`, у этого класса есть возможность указать количество используемых процессов (по умолчанию берется от количества ядер текущей системы), и через метод `map` указать функцию и коллекцию данных, каждый элемент данных будет передан в функцию, что запустится в процессе, причем `map` вернет список с результатами выполнения, поэтому можно без `Pipe` обойтись. Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/48f2b747bda410b9387f1be5175120fc07aec6f3/concurrency_in_python__threading_processing/multiprocessing__examples/hello_world__Pool_map.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как писали в комментарии multiprocessing это долго и кол-во процессов примерно должно быть равно кол-ву ядер процессора иначе теряется весь смысл. Попробуйте использовать потоки. Хотя чрезмерно большое кол-во потоков тоже не есть хорошо:

```py
from threading import Thread
import time

def func(x): # Ваша функция
    time.sleep(2)
    print("func", x)
    

for i in range(500): # Запуск в цикле
    potoc = Thread(target=func, args=[i], daemon=True)
    potoc.start()
potoc.join()
```

Comment: Если будет CPU нагрузка, то из-за GIL выгоды от использования потоков не будет. Да и 500 потоков больно дохрена, создание потоков и переключение между ними недешевая операция. Лучше через multiprocessing.Pool работать, это через процессы. Или через `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` если нужен тот же интерфейс, но через потоки. Тогда, их количество будет оптимальным для системы -- по количеству ядер. У меня есть несколько примеров разной реализации: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/48f2b747bda410b9387f1be5175120fc07aec6f3/concurrency_in_python__threading_processing

Comment: Если непонятно про CPU и GIL, то тут есть статья на примерах https://towardsdatascience.com/concurrency-in-python-e770c878ab53 и если посмотреть и сравнить примеры `Option 1: The baseline` (один поток) и `Option 2: using threads` (в несколько потоков), то пример с одним потоком будет быстрее из-за GIL, т.к. там нагрузка только на CPU, а не на I/O. Потому что он, GIL, синхронизирует потоки, поэтому код с потоками при операциях с CPU может быть медленнее, чем такой же, но в один поток (другое дело, если бы была работа с сетью или файловой системой, тогда был бы выигрыш)

Comment: Спасибо надо будет проверить такой вариант возможно будет плюс. Про GIL в моем примере как раз сжирается где-то 0,7секунды.